# How to modify decimals with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I print my array, it looks like this.

`print(cf)`

```
[[ 1.32641260e-01 -7.05267862e-01]
 [-7.09129315e-02  3.46919789e-01]
 [-1.62402115e-01  8.12157840e-01]
 [-2.55633585e-01  1.29801571e+00]
 [-3.22699255e-01  1.65070001e+00]
 [-3.57861306e-01  1.81832124e+00]
 [-3.87392942e-01  1.98105377e+00]
 [ 1.32641260e-01 -7.05267862e-01]
 [ 2.95642961e-01 -1.52509782e+00]]
```

But I want to modify the array looking like this so I can easily compare those values.

```
[[ 0.13235928 -0.69078624]
 [-0.06700144  0.32405811]
 [-0.16728665  0.84871924]
 [-0.25627623  1.30533686]
 [-0.32718223  1.67507062]
 [-0.34118729  1.74447093]
 [-0.38948283  2.00007669]
 [ 0.11188903 -0.58557467]
 [ 0.28579372 -1.46559478]]
```

How can I modify it by using `numpy`?

Comment: Just round the result for visual comparision, e.g. `cf.round(8)`

Comment: You can use `np.around([0.37, 1.64], decimals=1)` in numpy to convert. Please see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

Comment: @Alexander, could you demonstrate how rounding changes this display?  I think the problem in the first display is the scientific notation, not the number of decimals.  Or is it?

Comment: @hpaulj Using a Jupyter notebook, I get something similar to the OP's expected output using `cf.round(8)` where `cf` corresponds to the original numbers.  Note, for instance, that the first value of 1.32641260e-01 does not correspond to the OP's expected value of 0.13235928. In fact, many of the values are off. I assume that this is accidental rather than the true expected output.

Comment: @Alexander  The range of values in the `cf` display isn't wide enough to trigger scientific notation in `numpy`.  One or more needs to be around `1e-4`.  It's the smallest magnitude that matters, not the decimals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the print behavior globally (instead of each time you print), you can use `numpy.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` to change the numpy output so that it always prints floats and never falls back to the exponential format. Revert back to normal with `suppress=False`. If you need more decimal figures, use the function's `precision` argument.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using "print(np.around(cf,'int for decimal length'))". That should only go out x amount of decimal places that you want.